# Automate regression with specific dependent and independent variables

Tags: r, automation, regression, plm

MVE:
Let this be the data set:

```
data <- data.frame(year = rep(seq(1966,2015,1), 8), 
               county = c(rep('prva', 50), rep('druga', 50), rep('treća', 50), rep('četvrta', 50),
                          rep('peta', 50), rep('šesta', 50), rep('sedma', 50), rep('osma', 50)),
               crime1 = runif(400), crime2 = runif(400), crime3 = runif(400), 
               uvar1 = runif(400), uvar2 = runif(400), uvar3 = runif(400),
               var1 = runif(400), var2 = runif(400), var3 = runif(400), var4 = runif(400), var5 = runif(400))
```

Let's say crime1,2 and 3 are specific dependent variables. uvar1,2 and 3 are specific independent variables. var1,2 etc. are other covariates. What I'm trying to do is automate the regressions.

Namely, I want to get the result of this code:

```
plm(log(crime1) = log(univar1) + log(var1) + log(var2) + log(var3) + log(var4), model = 'within', effect = 'twoways', data = data)

plm(log(crime2) = log(univar2) + log(var1) + log(var2) + log(var3) + log(var4), model = 'within', effect = 'twoways', data = data)
```

etc.; but without writing 20 lines of code for each estimated model.

By looking at similar questions, this is as far as I'd come:

```
crime <- c('crime1', 'crime2', 'crime3')
plm.results <- lapply(data[, crime], function(y) plm(y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4, 
                                                     model = 'within', effect ='twoways', data = data))
```

Which certainly helps for my dependent variables, but I cannot figure how to include specific independent variables in each of these estimations. To clarify once more, I want univar1 to be in the first regression, but not in the rest of them etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formula` function is helpful when creating multiple sets of models. You could incorporate variations 
    using combination of `paste0` and `formula` with `lapply` to traverse the indices 1 to 3.

```
#remember to set.seed when sampling from distributions

set.seed(123)

#a helper function to create "log(var)" from "var"
fn_appendLog = function(x) {
 paste0("log(",x,")")
}



modelList = lapply(1:3,function(x) {


indepVars2 = Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep="+"),lapply(colnames(regDF)[grepl("^v",colnames(regDF))],fn_appendLog))

#> indepVars2
#[1] "log(var1)+log(var2)+log(var3)+log(var4)+log(var5)"


indepVars1 = fn_appendLog(paste0("uvar",x))

depVar = fn_appendLog(paste0("crime",x))

formulaVar = formula(paste0(depVar, " ~ ",indepVars1,"+", indepVars2))

#> formulaVar
#log(crime1) ~ log(uvar1) + log(var1) + log(var2) + log(var3) +  log(var4) + log(var5)


modelObj = plm(formulaVar, model = 'within', effect = 'twoways', data = regDF)


})
```

**Summary:**

```
summary(modelList[[1]])

#> summary(modelList[[1]])
#Twoways effects Within Model
#
#Call:
#plm(formula = formulaVar, data = regDF, effect = "twoways", model = "within")
#
#Balanced Panel: n=50, T=8, N=400
#
#Residuals :
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# -5.730  -0.396   0.116   0.599   1.520 
#
#Coefficients :
#             Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
#log(uvar1)  0.0393871  0.0490891  0.8024   0.4229
#log(var1)  -0.0369356  0.0541029 -0.6827   0.4953
#log(var2)  -0.0455269  0.0543664 -0.8374   0.4030
#log(var3)   0.0150516  0.0520347  0.2893   0.7726
#log(var4)  -0.0034534  0.0441506 -0.0782   0.9377
#log(var5)  -0.0109038  0.0527446 -0.2067   0.8363
#
#Total Sum of Squares:    302.23
#Residual Sum of Squares: 300.6
#R-Squared:      0.0053896
#Adj. R-Squared: 0.0045407
#F-statistic: 0.304357 on 6 and 337 DF, p-value: 0.93448
```

**Explanation:**

The independent variables are of two type, first `uvar1` and others `var1...varN`.

1) `colnames(regDF)[grepl("^v",colnames(regDF))]` this will give us a list of all variables
       in regDF which match pattern of beginning with letter 'v' with caret symbol signifying start of
       the string and `$` as end of the string, output at this stage is `c("var1","var2"...,"var5")`

2) We need log variants of this variable vector hence we pass them through `lapply` to the function
       `fn_appendLog`, which results in the list output of `list("log(var1)","log(var2)",...,"log(var5)")`

3) Next, we need these variables transformed as `log(var1)+log(var2)...+log(var5)`

4) To do so, we use function `Reduce` with the function `paste(x,y,sep="+")`, this takes
       each element of the above list with adjacent element and joins together with the seperator as "+"

```
   step1 = (log(var1)+log(var2))
   step2 = (log(var1)+log(var2)) + log(var3)
   step3 = (log(var1)+log(var2)+log(var3))+ log(var4) and so on
```

5) The function `Reduce` applies the function to the list and aggregates the output into a single vector
       resulting the final output of `log(var1)+log(var2)+log(var3)+log(var4)+log(var5)`

This might seem intimidating at first but as you use them often and explore examples they 
       will part of you repertoire in no time.The best way to learn about a function say `lapply` is to read the documentation of `?lapply` end to end and execute
       listed examples, tinker with parameters and gain familiarity. Hope this sheds some light
       on your query.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks ever so much!

Comment: Although it works perfectly, I would love to understand what exactly did you do here, and I struggle with this part:  indepVars2 = Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep="+"),
                      lapply(colnames(data)[grepl("^v",colnames(data))],fn_appendLog)) Could you please elaborate what exactly does this part do?

Comment: I have added some explanation on the steps involving `Reduce` and `lapply`, let me know if this would suffice.

Comment: I wanted to run the same code, but by using the felm function from felm package in order to obtain county-clustered standard errors. The code is otherwise identical, but for this line: modelObj = felm(formulaVar | county + year | 0 | county, data =regDf), but it won't work with felm function. It gives the following error: Error in terms(formula(as.Formula(formula), rhs = 1), specials = "G") : 
  object 'county' not found

Comment: Could you create a new post linking this question/answer and include libraries and other details regarding `felm` function

Comment: Thanks, the new question is up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494631/felm-function-doesnt-work-inside-lapply